# Etiquette to upvoting

Tags: discussion, up-votes

In general, I'm an overly positive, helpful, "go get-em" sort of person. You might see me on one of those stupid motivational posters giving you a kleenex after you trip over a misplaced mouse-cord (Perservere!)

I don't want to treat upvotes like a mere pat on the back. I like the need to *earn* reputation on Stack Overflow, vs. a simple "ra ra" attitude on other websites. Makes every point I get more valuable and fulfilling to me. But, I don't want to be a stingy jerk, either.

Any guidelines people use when upvoting answers and questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Was the answer **correct**?
- Was the answer **complete**?
- Was the answer **carefully explained** (for example a description or explanation provided, rather than simply a code or documentation reference)?
- Was the answer **unique** (that is, did the answer add information not present in any other responses)?

The first one is mandatory (at least for objective questions, where there *is* a correct answer); any combination of the others are good, the more the better.

Additionally, perhaps, for the really high-ranking responses:

- Did the answer **provoke debate or further discussion**?
- Did the answer **contribute knowledge or ideas** not previously published?

And, depending on the fickle demeanor of the community that day:

- Was the answer **funny**, particularly in some manner universally recognized by the geek culture?

How stringent I am at applying these criteria generally depends on the quality and difficulty of the answer. If it is a trivial question with a fairly trivial answer, I may not upvote any response, or only upvote the best answer of all. If it is a difficult question, particularly involving answers from multiple people to put together different parts of the puzzle, I might upvote everyone.

I generally don't downvote answers unless they are either:

- outright **incorrect**, or
- a **direct duplicate of an earlier response** (with no improvement in phrasing or additional references provided)

...but perhaps you are saving an "Etiquette for downvoting" question for tomorrow. :)

Comment: I happened to log on and find some discussions about down voting, and that discussion made sense: there's rarely a reason to; be constructive instead; save downvoting for a last resort/someone who doesn't take the advice given.

Answer (score 1):

The rollover text for the upvote button is my guidance: "This answer is useful".

Comment: +1 Maybe I have low standards, I dunno.