# Shouldn't tactical upvoting be discouraged?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is voting to balance in the spirit of the site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74666/is-voting-to-balance-in-the-spirit-of-the-site)

[Here are the guidelines for upvoting questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/29810/155739).

Unfortunately, it seems like people are upvoting some medium-quality questions, not because they think that the question deserved an upvote, but because they disagreed with an existing downvote.

Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422054/why-doesnt-the-js-file-work-in-another-folder#comment18342858_13422054), where the voter (who had around 2.4k rep at the time) left a comment explaining that his upvote was a tactical one:

> Who knows, fixed it by upvoting it back to 0..

"Fixed it"?! That offends me. We are supposed to be voting on the quality of the question, not meta-voting on the perceived quality of previous votes in order to try to skew the final, collated outcome.

That is, some other person had decided that the question was, in their mind, worthy of a downvote and it's not fair for that vote to have been "undone" purely on the merits of the vote itself.

Unfortunately I would also be offended were somebody to instruct me how I must cast my vote, so I don't see that there's a way to "fix" this problem. This was already covered in [a previous meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111801/155739) on the issue. The only real way to solve the problem would be to hide the question score entirely (akin to elections in which results are withheld until polls close), but then it's all rather pointless, isn't it?

However, surely we can state for the record that this behaviour ought to be *discouraged*?

Comment: This has definitely been discussed before. But I can't find it.

Comment: @Mysticial: Are you thinking of the very similar but not quite identical question I link to in my penultimate pargraph?

Comment: It wasn't that particular example, but it's along the same lines.

Comment: This is a similar discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74666/172431

Comment: Ultimately, voting is a personal choice, and that one example you found is from someone who's been here for all of 41 days. Is this really such a problem?

Comment: Oh, your question is at -1. Let me fix that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think it undermines the entire purpose of the voting system. If I'm going to take my time to vote on Stack Overflow, then I want question scores to mean something and _be useful_. Normalising to zero score for no actual reason is not useful.

Comment: @madth3: Oh, yes, I think that's a dupe actually. Ta.

Comment: I suppose if you actually explained the downvote, then it's less likely to get any mercy upvotes.

Comment: @Mysticial: Maybe. But I added my own downvote, with an explanation, and nobody seemed to change their mind.

Comment: Well... you kinda did it a bit after the fact...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So you downvoted a post just because someone else gave a pity upvote?  Doesn't that mean you were meta voting too?

Comment: I vaguely recall seeing an actual study on people's voting behavior on sites with similar post score systems, which found that (no matter how they were *told* to vote) most people subconsciously decided roughly what total score a post "deserved" and would vote it toward that score, whether up or down.

Comment: @Mysticial: No, I didn't. I wrote my comment 5 seconds before I cast my downvote, actually. Perhaps you're confusing my downvote for the question's first downvote.

Comment: @Servy: No, I downvoted it because it was a crap question, as I explained in detail in the comments of that question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ah. My bad. I was under the impression that you cast the first downvote.

Comment: @Mysticial: Nope, not me.

Comment: I suppose you're welcome to use the term "tactical" in whatever way you like, but your usage is inconsistent with the fairly well-established term "tactical downvoting," which means downvoting others' answers to a question you answered in an attempt to make yours rise higher and look better by comparison.

Comment: Also related: [Is voting to balance in the spirit of the site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74666/), [Is voting down supposed to mean “I don't like this question” or “This question has been voted up more than I can understand”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95209/) and [Should sympathy votes be used to counter unexplained downvotes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134613/)

Comment: It should be noted that the two people supporting the question have answers on the question. Therefore, they have a vested interest in keeping the question 'popular'.

Comment: I think this is the canonical Q&A on this topic: [Is there an actual "pity" or "sympathy" upvote problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93356/is-there-an-actual-pity-or-sympathy-upvote-problem)

Comment: @jadarnel27 that asks how much it happens; this is about what to do when it does happen.

Comment: @PopularDemand Good point.  I just wanted to point that question out, since it demonstrates that this isn't (or at least wasn't) really a problem.

Comment: I just had to mention that at the time of this comment the scores of each answer are, in order, +3/-3, +2/-2, +1/-1.  Either that's one hell of a coincidence, or everyone is making sure that any vote in either direction is cancelled out.

Comment: @PopularDemand: Actually I'm using it [the way the rest of the world uses it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactical_voting); I think SE's common definition of "tactical downvoting" is in fact slightly at odds with the broader common definition.

Comment: Indeed, and I intentionally avoided saying that anything was wrong with your way. But the "SE definition" is sensible in context, and I see it as a "when in Rome" situation.

Comment: @PopularDemand: Copy that.

Answer (score 5):

At the end of the day voting is subjective, and while we can provided intended guidelines, people can and will vote for whatever reason they want.  Voting fraud, in the form of sock puppeting, voting circles, or serial downvoting (the user, not the content) is the only form of voting that the community has considered it appropriate to actually regulate.

While voting, in either direction, for certain behaviors is liked/disliked by many individuals, restricting the freedom to vote would have major negative consequences.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should be discouraged.

That does not mean it needs to be regulated by moderators or the system though. Community policing and calling people out for doing so is the best way to discourage this practice. I know in the past I have encountered people that do this all the time. Supposedly they disagree with the ability of posts to go negative, so they upvote every negative post they see.

The community should stand together and let these people know that their actions are unwelcome in the community.

IOW: You did the right thing to bring it here and call the people out. Let the community decide how to balance the question/answer out and say what needs to be said to the people involved.

Comment: Related: [Is there an actual "pity" or "sympathy" upvote problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93356/is-there-an-actual-pity-or-sympathy-upvote-problem)

Comment: How would you propose to do so however without a clear admission of the voter on his behaviour and motivations?

Comment: I don't propose to do so.

Comment: So you feel very strongly about something you don't propose to take any action about? Interesting.

Comment: So this is all hypothetical then?

Comment: Um. I don't think you even read my answer. Not all 'solutions' are direct totalitarian actions.

Comment: I don't think you understand what the word "totalitarian" means.

Comment: @McCannot: I feel very strongly that our current politicians should not be in power at this exact present time. However, I do not propose to murder them or incite a coup.

Comment: Totalitarian, *adj.*: Of, related to, imposing, or being a system of government in which consumption of only one brand of breakfast cereal is allowed.

Comment: @Shog9 this is all a ruse to make us argue over which cereal to choose and forget about the waffle option altogether, isn't it? Crafty.

Comment: @PopularDemand Total waffles?  Might have to try that sometime.

Answer (score 1):

The comment

> Who knows, fixed it by upvoting it back to 0.

just made the author's intent explicit.  Beyond that, there's little way of determining someone's intent with their voting.

If I vote for a particular candidate, am I voting for the candidate, or voting against his opponents?  You don't really know unless I tell you.

If such tactical voting gets flagged, then people will just stop commenting on why they're voting the way they do.  It won't eliminate tactical voting.

Maybe I vote something up because the downvote got my attention, and I think, "The question/answer is better than the downvotes suggest," and I have the option to cast my vote.  That's in essence what the person at the top of my answer did.

But let's chase the rabbit a little more: "What is a tactical vote?"  What makes it tactical?  Why is one vote tactical but another isn't?  If a person isn't in effect voting twice or voting for his own stuff, what does it matter what you call it?

Comment: Normal voting is voting +1 or 0 or -1 on the question's quality. Tactical voting is voting for your desired final score, and it's completely silly!

Comment: I agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit for the most part, but I frequently vote in order to push the best answer to the top, even if there are a few other answers that probably deserve a vote. Is there something wrong with that? Is that "tactical"? Is it bad that I want (what I perceive to be) the best answer to have the highest score?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: That's an entirely reasonable purpose for voting on answers--not so much on questions, though.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "entirely reasonable" but it's certainly not something that I personally would go out of my way to discourage. Unlike for questions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What? Once a questioner has solved their problem, the only reason for the post to exist is as a resource for other people encountering the same problem. Ranking answers by how useful they are is not just *reasonable*, it's *the essential reason* for voting on answers at all.

Comment: @McCannot: But Stack Exchange has decided that the rank of usefulness be determined by the OP "accepting" a single answer. There is no indication that the +1/0/-1 voting system should work any other way for answers than it does for questions; it's just a bit less important. _We do not rank posts_: posts are ranked automatically by collating the votes of _multiple_ people, so by trying to manipulate the final score on your own, you're subverting that community-driven mechanism.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So your contention is that people exercising their ability to vote are subverting the community mechanism of "people can exercise their ability to vote"? That's double-plus ungood, indeed.

Comment: @McCannot: Perverse, isn't it! :)